# upgrade android app , how to override sqlite

Tags: android, upgrade

i have a android app of version 4.20 inside 10M sqlitedb, now i have a app of version 4.21 inside 100M sqlitedb,i want upgrade 4.20 to 4.21, when it upgrade have completed, i find the sqlite size still keep 10M in 4.21 app.

so the question is how to override sqlitedb when upgrade app 4.20 -> 4.21 。

---

My business is: app will have a lot of data synchronization. In order to optimize, every app will fill in initialization data into SQLite when it is published. Therefore, after each app have upgraded, I hope to completely overwrite SQLite。

any help is very apprecated.

Comment: can you explain more? Do you want to just recreate db?

Comment: @golkarm96  My business is: app will have a lot of data synchronization. In order to optimize, every app will fill in initialization data into SQLite when it is published. Therefore, after each app is upgrad, I hope to completely overwrite SQLite

Comment: You can easily upgrade your database version and drop all tables in the `onUpgrade()` method and after that you can build again your database. Tell me if you need another thing or I send it as an answer with more details

Comment: @golkarm96 thank you very much,i have slove it 。    ```    @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  
  if(oldVersion != newVersion) context.deleteDatabase("LFX.db");
 }   ```

Comment: you doesn't need to check `oldVersion != newVersion` because this method only used for upgrades, not equals versions and not for downgrades. if you need to do some thing on downgrade too, so you must override it

Comment: accept my answer if it was useful, and tell me if there are any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade your database version and in the `onUpgrade()` method of your SQLiteOpenHelper drop all tables and call `onCreate()` method for recreat database.

```java
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    ...

    private void resetDB(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        
        // Drop all tables 
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name");
        // TODO duplicate above line for other tables
        
        // Crate tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        resetDB(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        super.onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        resetDB(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is the onUpgrade function is not being called because when you load a database from assets the the default version is **0**.

And when you call the db.getReadableDatabase() or db.getWriteableDatabase which is supposed to call the onUpgrade method, it fails because the version number 0 which is supposed to be a fresh database.

If you see the SqliteOpenHelper source code

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
  //Skips updating in your case
  if (version == 0) {
  onCreate(db);
  } else {
  if (version > mNewVersion) {
    onDowngrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
  } else {
   onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
  }
}
db.setVersion(mNewVersion);
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
   db.endTransaction();
}
```

When version number of db is is **0** the `onUpgrade` function is not called.

One way to fix the problem is change the version number of db when you add it to the asset or change it before opening

The solution change the version number and your problem

```
try
 {
   String myPath = MyApplication.context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
   //open a database directly without Sqliteopenhelper 
   SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
   //if the version is default 0 the update the version
   if (myDataBase.getVersion() == 0)
    {
     //update the database version to the previous one
     myDataBase.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version = " + 1);
    }
    //Close DataBase 
    myDataBase.close();
  }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     //Do Nothing a fresh install happened
   }
```